# Golang string to uint

Tags: go

In my project, ID is designed as snowflakeid. The front end passes a string to me, and the database storage is bigint. This means that before I store it, it needs to be converted to uint. Please tell me what to do?
demo data :

```
m := "156343853366906880"
```

my code:

```
u, _ := strconv.ParseUint(m, 0, 19)
```

The expected results are accurate and will not lose accuracy

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Sorry it's my problem, my english is not good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SnowflakeID](https://github.com/dustinrouillard/snowflake-id#snowflake-id) is a time based 64-bit unique id. Since you need to convert string to a 64-bit number, `strconv.ParseUint()` is quite good. See, the reference at [ParseUint](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#ParseUint).

In your code, you used 19 as bit size. Do not mix it with the number of digit(s) in the integer (unsigned) represented by the string from frontend.

For convert a 64-bit SnowflakeID (string) into a 64-bit unsigned integer, use 64 as bitSize arg.

```golang
U, err := strvonv.ParseUint(s, 0, 64)
if err != nil {
    // handle error... 
}
```

> Also do not try to ignore error, when it really matters.

Answer (score 2):

Third parameter of `strconv.parseUint()` is `bitSize`. 19 bits are not sufficient to represents the number `156343853366906880`. So the method returns an error. (which you are ignoring by assigning it to `_`)

```
m := "156343853366906880"
_, err := strconv.ParseUint(m, 0, 19)
fmt.Println(err)
//strconv.ParseUint: parsing "156343853366906880": value out of range 524287
```

2^19 - 1 = 524287 is the biggest unsigned number that can be represented with 19 bits.

Pass 64 as bitSize :

```
m := "156343853366906880"
u, err := strconv.ParseUint(m, 0, 64)
if err == nil {
    fmt.Print(u)
    //156343853366906880
}
```

If your number is going to greater than `uint64` use `big.Int` :

[string to big Int in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783352/string-to-big-int-in-go/46783431#46783431)